# html2pdf output displaying question mark in pdf for greek characters

Tags: php, html2pdf

In Codeigniter, I am using the html2pdf library to generate PDF from HTML.
I have an issue of greek characters are displaying with a question mark in PDF.

From far, I know its because of ASCII to UTF-8 conversion.

I manually also try to convert a string from ASCII to UTF-8 but that also not work for me.

```
$address = 'Αργοστολίου,
            abc';
$cmp_address = iconv(mb_detect_encoding($address, mb_detect_order(), true), "UTF-8", $address);

$this->html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P', 'A4', 'en',true,'UTF-8');

$this->html2pdf->pdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
$this->html2pdf->writeHTML($cmp_address,false);
$this->html2pdf->Output('address.pdf', "D");
```

PDF is downloading. But it contains a question mark(?) instead of variable address value.

PDF Current output :

```
???????????,
abc
```

PDF expected output :

```
Αργοστολίου,
abc
```

All suggestions are welcome 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a chance that these symbols are not present in font used for output?

Comment: @SergiyT. Thanks for reply, For that, I also use two-three different greek types of font and set with  $this->html2pdf->setDefaultFont('greek'); but still its not converting to actual value.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Problem fixed using this link

https://github.com/spipu/html2pdf/issues/268

The solution is to set the font family to "font-family: freeserif;" with inline CSS to each element in Greek.